# write a big size Matrix in Matlab and read in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, file, matrix

I need to write a matrix( different sizes) to a file in matlab and read that matrix from that file in c++ and store in an array.
can anyone help me?

is saved my matrix in txt file in matlab using :

```
dlmwrite('f:\ThetaR.txt', thetaPrim, 'delimiter', '\t','precision',4) // thetaPrim is the name of my matrix
```

But i cannot store it in c++. 
if a dynamic way to take the matrix is much better however this wy is not working too

```
float thetaR [i][j];
ifstream in("f:\\ThetaR.txt"); 
if (!in) { std::cout << "Cannot open file.\n"; return; } 
for (y = 0; y < j; y++)  { 
    for (x = 0; x < i; x++)  {    
        in >> theta[x][y];  
    }
```

i have shown matrix as a string too but how can i split them because there is no letter between them

this is the code :

```
ifstream in("f:\\ThetaR.txt");

if (!in) {
    std::cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
    return;   
}

std::string line;

while (std::getline(in, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::cout << line ; 
}
```

see the output :

[image: screencap of a command window with a bunch of numbers in it]

Comment: How did you attempt to read the matrix in C++? Do you have some code that does not work?

Comment: `std::ifstream`, `std::getline`

Comment: @MattPhillips i have tried but not working,` ifstream in("f:\\ThetaR.txt");

  if (!in) {
    std::cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
    return;
  }

  for (y = 0; y < j; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < i; x++) {
      in >> distances[x][y];
    }`

Comment: is it possible to read from file and save to an array straightly?

Comment: If that is your code in the comment above, then edit the question, adding the code. It will be easier for the rest of us to review.  Be sure to indent the code four spaces so the SO system automatically beautifies the post.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you, your second way should reproduce the matrix (but get rid of `std::istringstream iss(line);`, it does nothing).  You still will need to tokenize each line of course.  Open up ThetaR.txt in WordPad or something and verify that you've written it correctly.  Also see what happens in Linux or MacOS if those platforms are available to you.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see with the double for statements bundled together, but the closing curly brace of the outer for loop is missing.  There are three added comments to help understanding.  Modified code:

```
//
// Assumed that i and j have valid values before using them below.
// If not, then the thetaR array will not have any of the expected data
// and the double for loop will not behave as expected.  Hence, no data
// will be read and/or memory overruns and/or undefined behavior and/or
// application crash.
//
float thetaR [i][j];

ifstream in("f:\\ThetaR.txt"); 
if (!in) 
{ 
  std::cout << "Cannot open file.\n"; 
  return; 
} 

for (y = 0; y < j; y++)  
{ 
  for (x = 0; x < i; x++)  
  {    
     in >> thetaR[x][y];  // Added the R to the array variable name
  }
} // added this to close outer for loop
```